# Can Manipulate's execution result be represented by In&Out Cell?

Tags: cells, cellprint, cellgroup

I wrote the following code.

```
Manipulate[Style[Control@{{in, ""}, InputField[#, Boxes] &, 
ImageSize -> {400, {40, Automatic}}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}},16], 
Button["Evaluate", {CopyToClipboard[RawBoxes@in], 
show = {RawBoxes@in, If[StringQ[in], evaluate[evaluate[in]], evaluate[in] ]},   
CellPrint[CellGroup[{
  ExpressionCell[ 
   Grid[{{Style[" In[#]:=", 9, RGBColor[0, 0.25, 0.5]], 
      show[[1]]}}, ItemSize -> {{4, 45}, Automatic}, 
    Alignment -> Left], "Print", Editable -> False, 
   CellMargins -> {{10, 0}, {3, 5}}],    
  
  ExpressionCell[
   Grid[{{Style["Out[#]=", 9, RGBColor[0, 0.25, 0.5]], 
      Style@show[[2]]}}, ItemSize -> {{4, 45}, Automatic}, 
    Alignment -> Left], "Print", Editable -> False, 
   CellMargins -> {{10, 0}, {5, 3}}]} ]]  }], 
ContinuousAction -> False, AppearanceElements -> None,
Initialization :> ( show = {{1, 2}};   
Off[ToExpression::esntx];   
evaluate[in_] := 
ToExpression[
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket[in]]])]
```

When you do this, it appears as follows.

[image]

I want to CellPrint the representation of input and output on the screen above. Like Mathhematica's Notebook.

[image]

The results I want are as follows.

(1) Numbering such as In[#], Ou[#], forming cell groups.

(2) Delete the cell number specified as PopupMenu with the Delete button

Literally, I want to recreate the expression of Mathematica Notebook as it is.

[image]